# How to hide only the columns of this group when hovering over a group column in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default, hover hides all other columns in all groups. How can I make it so that only the columns in that group are hidden on hover?
I found the hover event in the documentation, and getting the column (upper left), but how to hide it with it? Maybe through `tooltip` somehow?

My [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1405261/297806) in original view.

An example of how it works now:
[image: Пример как работает сейчас:]

Example how to:
[image: Пример как надо]

```js
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart_1',
    type: 'column',
    height: 350,
 },

 title: {
    text: 'Some text'
 },
 xAxis: {
    categories: ['Processing.js', 'Impact.js', 'Other', 'Ease.js', 'Box2D.js', 'WebGL', 'DOM', 'CSS', 'Canvas', 'Javascript']
 },
 yAxis: {
    title: {
       text: 'Title y'
    }
 },
 /*tooltip: {
   shared: true,
   split: true,
 },*/
 plotOptions: {
   series: {
            point: {
              events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                  var chart = this.series.chart;
                  if (!chart.lbl) {
                        chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                            .attr({
                                padding: 10,
                                r: 10,
                                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            })
                            .css({
                                color: '#FFFFFF'
                            })
                            .add();
                    }
                    chart.lbl
                        .show()
                        .attr({
                            text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y
                        });
                }
              }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function (){
                    if (this.chart.lbl) {
                        this.chart.lbl.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        column: {
          groupPadding: 0.1,
          pointPadding: 0.1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
              console.log("1");
            }
          }
        }
 },
 series: [{
    name: 'Dev #1',
    data: [5, 10, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 40, 80, 90]
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #2',
    data: [15, 15, 18, 40, 30, 25, 60, 60, 80, 70]
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #3',
    data: [1, 3, 6, 0, 50, 25, 50, 60, 30, 100]
 }]
});
```

```css
.actions, .chart {
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart_1" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, at first you need to set the `opacity` to `1` for `inactive` series and disable `hover`.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        },
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
```

Then, use the `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` point events to find the points with the same category as the hovering one, and to update them with new opacity.

```
point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        var point = this,
          chart = point.series.chart,
          allSeries = chart.series,
          category = point.category;
        allSeries.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            if (point.category === category) {
              point.update({
                opacity: 0.2
              }, false)
            }
          })
        })
        chart.redraw()
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        var point = this,
          chart = point.series.chart,
          allSeries = chart.series,
          category = point.category;
        allSeries.forEach(series => {
          series.points.forEach(point => {
            point.update({
              opacity: 1
            }, false)
          })
        })
        chart.redraw()
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lcn6d8e/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. But for my purposes it was necessary to change the condition a little: onMouseOver `((point.category === category) && (point !== this))`